# An expression to show values beginning only with a character

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have a procedure witch return a number if name is NULL and feeds the field in SSRS as shown below.
[image]
The report has 10 pages (based on a date selected) and I'd like to put rows which has the names at top of the report in alphabetical order and those with number in the field at the bottom.
I've tried to accomplish that with 2 inner tables with a different tablix visibility, but expression as "Asc(LEFT(Fields!station_name.Value, 1)) > 64" returns an error

```
The Hidden expression for the Tablix7 contains an error: String length argument must be higher than zero.
```

[image]
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are just trying to sort the groups by names then numbers you can use two sort expressions in your Station_Name group.

Set the first group expression to be soemthing like

```
=IIF(Isnumeric(Fields!Station_Name.Value),1,0)
```

and the second group to just

```
Fields!Station_Name.Value
```

The first group expression will return 0 for non numeric station names and 1 for numeric station names so all the non numeric ones will apeear first, then they will be sorted by the name itself.

Comment: can you post a screenshot of the group sort properties and each expression and explain what result you get when you try the expression I provided.

Comment: I had to forget visibility expression somewhere. I've tried it again and it works well now. The sorting order is in desired way. Thank you very much!